# Multiple views inheriting the same translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, locale, yaml, rails-i18n

Right now I have a `pirate.yml` in `locales` with the following structure:

```
pirate:
  posts:
    index:
      page_title: Some posts
      navigation: Some navs over here
    index_test:
      page_title: Some posts
      navigation: Some navs over here
```

Can I avoid this duplication somehow?

In a css-file with [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) it would have looked like this:

```
pirate:
  posts:
    index:, index_test:
      page_title: Some posts
      navigation: Some navs over here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with anchors (`&`) and aliases (`*`):

```
pirate:
  posts:
    index: &default
      page_title: Some posts
      navigation: Some navs over here
    index_test: *default
```

You can also use merge (`<<`) to amend the values:

```
pirate:
  posts:
    index: &default
      page_title: Some posts
      navigation: Some navs over here
    index_test:
      <<: *default
      page_title: Some new posts
      comment: Some optional comment
```